# Split a single string into an array using specific Regex rules

Tags: php, regex

I'm processing a single string which contains many pairs of data. Each pair is separated by a `;`  sign. Each pair contains a number and a string, separated by an `=`  sign.

I thought it would be easy to process, but i've found that the string half of the pair can contain the `=`  and `;` sign, making simple splitting unreliable.

Here is an example of a problematic string:

```
123=one; two;45=three=four;6=five;
```

For this to be processed correctly I need to split it up into an array that looks like this:

```
'123', 'one; two'
'45',  'three=four'
'6',   'five'
```

I'm at a bit of dead end so any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to everyone for the help, this is where I am so far:

```
$input = '123=east; 456=west';

// split matches into array
preg_match_all('~(\d+)=(.*?);(?=\s*(?:\d|$))~', $input, $matches);

$newArray = array();

// extract the relevant data
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[2]); $i++) {
    $type   = $matches[2][$i];
    $price  = $matches[1][$i];

    // add each key-value pair to the new array
    $newArray[$i] = array(
        'type'      => "$type",
        'price'     => "$price"
    );
}
```

Which outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => east
            [price] => 123
        )

)
```

The second item is missing as it doesn't have a semicolon on the end, i'm not sure how to fix that.

I've now realised that the numeric part of the pair sometimes contains a decimal point, and that the last string pair does not have a semicolon after it. Any hints would be appreciated as i'm not having much luck.

Here is the updated string taking into account the things I missed in my initial question (sorry):

```
12.30=one; two;45=three=four;600.00=five
```

Comment: You want to have a flat array of 6 elements?

Comment: Also, if a `;` appears in the pair, is it always followed by a space?

Comment: I'm using array_combine to sort the array the way I want, which is   `[123] => one; two;` and so on. `;` and `=` in the pair won't always be followed by a space. Thanks.

Comment: Ok i'm not longer using array_combine as it messes up the order of the results. Instead i'm iterating through the matches array and creating a new array with the correct key-value pairs and in the correct order.

Comment: I've updated my post with my current code - cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a look-ahead assertion for this; the look-ahead matches if a `;` is followed by a digit or the end of your string:

```
$s = '12.30=one; two;45=three=four;600.00=five';

preg_match_all('/(\d+(?:.\d+)?)=(.+?)(?=(;\d|$))/', $s, $matches);

print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [12.30] => one; two
    [45] => three=four
    [600.00] => five
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the regex you want:

```
\s*(\d+)\s*=(.*?);(?=\s*(?:\d|$))
```

The trick is to consider only the semicolon that's followed by a digit as the end of a match. That's what the lookahead at the end is for.

You can see a detailed visualization on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5Cs%2a%28%5Cd%2b%29%5Cs%2a=%28.%2a?%29;%28?=%5Cs%2a%28?%3a%5Cd%7C%24%29%29&flags=&str=123=one;%20two;45=three=four;6=five;).

Comment: Thanks, that works well, although i've now realised that the numeric part of the pair sometimes contains a decimal point, and that the last string pair does not have a semicolon after it. Any hints would be appreciated, i'm playing around in RegexBuddy but not getting very far. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following `preg_match_all` code to capture that:

```
$str = '123=one; two;45=three=four;6=five;';
if (preg_match_all('~(\d+)=(.+?);(?=\d|$)~', $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/MG3BaO

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '123=one; two;45=three=four;6=five;';

preg_match_all('/(\d+)=([a-zA-z ;=]+)/', $str,$matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

o/p:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123=one; two;
            [1] => 45=three=four;
            [2] => 6=five;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => one; two;
            [1] => three=four;
            [2] => five;
        )

)
```

then y can combine

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]));
echo '</pre>';
```

o/p:

```
Array
(
    [123] => one; two;
    [45] => three=four;
    [6] => five;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but this code is written in c#, you can change it into php

```
 string[] res = Regex.Split("123=one; two;45=three=four;6=five;", @";(?=\d)");
```

--SJ